# Render TeeChart for PHP in another page

Tags: php, teechart

I am a newbie on TeeChart for PHP.

All examples I have found are rendering the chart on the same php file where it has been created.

I would like to build the chart using a PHP script, which receives some parameters via AJAX, and render the chart on the page which has generated the AJAX call.

Is that possible? Any example on that?

Best regards.

Jayme Jeffman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a simple example:

**getchart.php:**

```
<?php
  // get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];


//Includes
include "../../sources/TChart.php";

$chart1 = new TChart(600,450);
$chart1->getChart()->getHeader()->setText($q);
$chart1->getAspect()->setView3D(false);

$line1 = new Line($chart1->getChart());
$line1->setColor(Color::RED());
$chart1->addSeries($line1);

// Speed optimization
$chart1->getChart()->setAutoRepaint(false);

for($t = 0; $t <= 10; ++$t) {
  $line1->addXY($t, (10 + $t), Color::RED());
}

$chart1->getChart()->setAutoRepaint(true);

$chart1->render("chart1.png");    
$rand=rand();
echo "chart1.png?rand=".$rand;
?>
```

**Test.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showChart(str) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {           
            var image = document.getElementById("get_img");
            image.src = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getchart.php?q="+str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Enter the chart title below:</b></p>
<form>
Chart title: <input type="text" onkeyup="showChart(this.value)">
</form>
<p><img id="get_img" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```